# Can the fragile base class problem occur in C++?

Tags: c++

I stumbled across the [Fragile Base Class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_base_class) Wikipedia article.

I understand the infinite cycle caused by the last example. But to my understanding, it can not occur in C++, as in C++ the compiler would compile `inc1()` once for all into binary code with hard coded jump to `Super`'s  `inc2` (instead of `Sub`'s `inc2`). Is this correct?

Comment: It can still happen with `virtual` methods

Comment: Also, in some cases, you can trigger it by overriding methods even without `virtual`, in cases with static dispatch.

Comment: please include the relevant example in the question. Without the wiki article it is hard to make sense out of the question and the answer

Answer (score 3):

[Konrad Rudolph shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60381182/2805305) that C++ has this exact same problem. I want to present here some **solutions**

A solution mentioned in the wiki is to make `inc2` final.

However, depending on your situation, a better solution could be to explicitly call the base method from `Base`:

```
class Base {
    int counter = 0;

public:
    virtual void inc1() { Base::inc2(); } // <-- now safe
    virtual void inc2() { ++counter; }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void inc2() override { inc1(); }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The example in the article is directly translatable to C++, and exhibits the same issue:

```
class Super {
    int counter = 0;

public:
    // First version:
    // virtual void inc1() { ++counter; }
    // Changed to:
    virtual void inc1() { inc2(); }
    virtual void inc2() { ++counter; }
};

class Sub : public Super {
public:
    void inc2() override { inc1(); }
};
```